# My html div is making grow their parent container beyond its limit

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem: My **div** (red one) that is inside a table-td (that I cannot change), is making the parent container grow and show a scroll not matter which percentage I use for my **div** width.

[image: Design of my page]

The following image shows the actual problem:

[image]

I also have an example in fiddle

[Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/e2q7qf80/1/)

```
<div class="principal"> 
<table width="100%" class="sometable"><tbody><tr><td> 

    <!-- my code starts here -->
<div id="div_translation_container">
    <div class="taxonomy_section_body">
        <div class="taxonomy_section_row">
          <div class="taxonomy_section_cell">6000 ABD</div>
          <div class="taxonomy_section_cell">
             i
          </div>
          <div class="taxonomy_section_cell">
             i
          </div>
          <div class="taxonomy_section_cell">
             i
          </div>
          <div class="taxonomy_section_cell">
             i
          </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div> 
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- my code ends here -->


    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.principal{
    width:900px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow:auto;
}

#div_translation_container{
    background-color:red;
    border-top: 2px solid #141414;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}

.taxonomy_section_body {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.taxonomy_section_row {
    background-color: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.taxonomy_section_cell {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The table width is 100%
The columns is 80%
and my **div** is 50%

but somehow these percentages are not considered..

**NOTE*** I cannot change the table or the principal div because my html code is encrusted dynamically, and it shouldn't affect anything outside its boundaries

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
#div_translation_container{
.....
position:absolute;
}
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hoj2Lwdv/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, just remove overflow or make overflow:hidden to .principal:

```
.principal{
    width:900px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I cannot change principal (because my div is incrusted dinamically), is there any other way?

Comment: You can't change the CSS for it? The HTML would remain the same.

Comment: No I can't, and also I should not, because it is a WCM enterprise web site.

Comment: Can you add another div inside principal, and make that one width 900px and overflow hidden?

Comment: yes I can, but the width needs to be a percentage :( because 900px only was an example, I do not know the parent width

Comment: try this: width: 100vw; http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units and http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. Initially, you had your section body display property set to inline-block. I only removed it, since all your divs are wrapped inside the table (display:table if you were to style it in CSS) to avoid display issues.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoj2Lwdv/5/)

```
.principal{
width:600px;
height: 300px;
background-color:black;
overflow:auto;
```

}

```
#div_translation_container{
background-color:red;
border-top: 2px solid #141414;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 60%;
position:absolute;
```

}

```
.taxonomy_section_body {

margin: auto;
min-height: 10px;
overflow-x: auto;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

}

```
.taxonomy_section_row {
background-color: yellow;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

```
.taxonomy_section_cell {
background-color: blue;
display:inline-block;
width: 250px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 30px;
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: nice solution, but now div_translation_container does not respect the width of its parent

Comment: I'm assuming it's your div element with the class principle that's causing the issue. But if you can't change it, then it's always going to stay that way. At least this is my assumption. Hope you find a better solutions :)

Comment: thank you, My div that is incrusted (div_translation_container) shouldn't affect its parent  :(  but there is something in my div that makes their parent behave odd